# App rotates when UIAlertView is shown in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uialertview

I am working on an app that is mostly used in portrait mode (except for a few views).
We are encountering an issue in iOS 8 where the app is able to rotate when an `UIViewAlert` is shown, even though the underlaying view controller only supports portrait orientation and its `shouldAutorotate` method returns NO. The rotation is not even full as the `UIAlertView` rotates to landscape, but the underlying view remains in portrait mode. There is no problem if we run the app in iOS 7.

I know that `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in iOS 8 and that we should now use `UIAlertController`. However, I would really like to avoid having to replace it as this would mean editing 50+ classes that use `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertViewDelegate`. Also, we still support iOS 7 so I would have to have both solutions. I would prefer only to have to do this once, when we make the full switch to iOS 8.

Comment: Thank you for writing Suraj. However, this is exactly the solution I am hoping to avoid :)

Comment: The problem is, Apple changed their internal implementation of alert views. They use a `UIAlertController` internally, and it being a view controller, is asked if it supports rotation or not. The default implementation supports rotation, so you see the behaviour you describe.

Comment: That makes sense Leo. So how do I prevent this, short of subclassing it and changing the all my classes?

Comment: I'd pitch some bounty on this for a decent answer that doesn't require changing my 50+ AlertViews.

Comment: @NobleK Make sure to open a bug report with Apple. Silmaril's answer is correct right now (as of iOS 8.3 beta), but it relies on a second bug in Apple's implementation, and may stop functioning. Open a bug report about `UIAlertView`. Thanks

Comment: @LeoNatan if Apple fixes the original UIAlertView rotation bug, then my workaround won't be needed :)

Comment: @Silmaril Yes, but for the mm to fix it, you have to let them know about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put this in your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation

**Swift**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if window == self.window {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)  // Mask for all supported orientations in your app
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue) // Supported orientations for any other window (like one created for UIAlert in iOS 8)
    }
}

}
```

**Objective-C**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if (window == self.window) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; // Mask for all supported orientations in your app
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // Supported orientations for any other window (like one created for UIAlert in iOS 8)
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Rotation methods are not called for alert window.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I tested this code before posting it. And it worked.

Comment: I checked, and indeed the alert shim window is tested against this method. Both behaviors are bugs, as a system window should not be passed in public delegate method, but also alert shim window should only rotate as the original window it was opened from, not as its root controller tells it.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this all day thanks! Worked flawlessly for my app need. #swift

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate: (This is only a hack. I'd be glad to see a more elegant solution)

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    UIViewController *presentedViewController = window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    if (!presentedViewController) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }

    Class alertControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController");
    if (!alertControllerClass) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    if ([presentedViewController isKindOfClass:alertControllerClass] || [presentedViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:alertControllerClass]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue with my app, I resolved it by subclassing the

> UIAlertViewController

and implementing the these orientation methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)); }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES; }

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; }
```

Comment: Haroon, if I use `UIAlertViewController` I don't have any problems at all. But as I have written I would like to avoid replacing all of my `UIViewAlert` instances with `UIAlertViewController`.

Comment: Ok in that case you may use other solutions but I not sure It may/may not cause issues in future but I was facing a lot issues with UIPickerController UIActionSheet, MFMailViewController etc. because after the dismissal of these controllers UIAlertView start ignoring the orientations.